# Setup Cassandra for Django failed on Ant: Unable to find a javac compiler;

Tags: java, django, ant, cassandra

I've followed this guide:
https://github.com/ericflo/twissandra

I'm failed on:

```
cd cassandra
ant
```

where it give message:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/z/cassandra/build.xml:348: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre"

Total time: 6 minutes 15 seconds
```

I don't know anything about Java

Answer (score 1):

You need a JDK (Java Development Kit) for that operation. My best guess it that you only have the JRE (Java Runtime Environment)

If you are running Ubuntu and want to install the sun/oracle jdk version:

```
$sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: Missed the "java-6-openjdk" part. If you have successfully installed the openjdk that should be enough. The classpath might be wrong though.

Comment: There are separate packages for openjdk-6-jre and openjdk-6-jdk, so he doesn't necessarily have a JDK installed.